# ssh permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I was able to access a remote server via ssh before. but I am not able to access it when I am in a different country now. it says 'permission denied'. the username and password is the same.sometimes it says 'Read from remote host ......: Connection reset by peer'. any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This leaves me wondering a few things...

- Is the remote server yours? The owner could have denyhosts set up and only allow clients to access it from a single IP.
- Are you using your internet connection or someone elses?
- Have you always used username/password or SSH keys?

The owner could have configured reverse lookups so that users must be within a certain area. Certain geographical locations could also be blocked. Depending on which country you are in, the internet you are being provided may be highly restricted to the point that SSH connections are blocked. The person who has control of the modem/router could also be blocking certain traffic.